# Angular Material Mat-Select ngModel boolean Value Not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngmodel

I use mat-select  To select a user's gender in angular 7 project and angular material

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Gender" required 
            formControlName="isMale" 
            [(ngModel)]="userProfile.isMale">
            <mat-option value="false">Women</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="true">Men</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-hint align="end">Please Select...</mat-hint>
          <mat-error *ngIf="isControlHasError('isMale','required')"><strong>Please Select Gender</strong>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

userProfile get from server and isMale property is boolean type but after get data do not show selected value on mat-select
I Also use this way but not work

```
        <mat-option [value]="'false'">Women</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="'true'">Men</mat-option>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

finally i use `this.postForm.controls['isMale'].setValue(profile.isMale?'true':'false');` after get model from server set manually mat-select and convert boolean to string

Answer (score 11):

This has worked for me (I am using Angular 8)

```
   <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="userProfile.isMale">
      <mat-option [value]="true">Men</mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="false">Women</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Note that I used [value] = "true or false" without any single cotes. Obviously, userProfile.isMale should be boolean (true or false).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using formControlName and [(ngModel)] together. In angular 7 we can't use these together. So may be that's why your ngModel is not working.

You can use following method to get selected value:

```
formName.controls['isMale'].value;
```

and you can set the value to this formcontrol like this:

```
formName.controls['isMale'].setValue(true);
```

where formName is your formGroup name.

Comment: tank you for answer i remove formControlName and only use ngmodel but not work . and remove ngModel and add this.postForm.controls['isMale'].setValue(userProfile.isMale) ; and not work  and also test this.postForm.controls['isMale'].setValue(True or false) and 'True' 'False'  and not work

Comment: If you are using only [(ngModel)] then you have to set name property, then only it will work.

Comment: finally i use  this.postForm.controls['isMale'].setValue(profile.isMale?'true':'false');  after get model from server set manually mat-select and convert boolean to string but i think can bind boolean to mat-select

Answer (score 0):

```
     <mat-option value="true"> Yes </mat-option>
     <mat-option value="false"> No </mat-option>
```

it will return you like IsApplicable="true" as string

```
     <mat-option [value]="true"> Yes </mat-option>
     <mat-option [value]="false"> No </mat-option>
```

this [value]="true" returns IsApplicable=true as string value

```
     <mat-option [ngValue]="true"> Yes </mat-option>
     <mat-option [ngValue]="false"> No </mat-option>
```

use [ngValue] to return Boolean value